# insert type=block in magento cms page

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm install news module, and want to show latest news on main page in cms page content. In the module xml i'm find

```
 <reference name="right">
            <block type="clnews/settings" name="right.clnews.menu" before="-">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="clnews/news/showrightblock">
                    <template>clnews/menu.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest" after="right.clnews.menu">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="clnews/news/showlatestnews">
                    <template>clnews/latest.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

in the end of file i added

```
<cms_index_index>

     <block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="clnews/news/showlatestnews">
                    <template>clnews/latest.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>

</cms_index_index>
```

in cms page i wrote

```
{{block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest" template="clnews/latest.phtml"}}
```

but in main page i d'not see my block, what the problem?

p/s latest news config is enable

Comment: {{block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest" template="clnews/latest.phtml" ifconfig="clnews/news/showlatestnews" }} try this

Comment: not working:(((

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you whitelist that block type? You can do this via `System > Permissions > Blocks`.

Comment: Please try to keep the block name different in cms home page then define in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your block inside `content` block. ie.

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="content">
       <block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest">
           <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="clnews/news/showlatestnews">
               <template>clnews/latest.phtml</template>
           </action>
       </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Then clear your cache and you are good to go.

Another alternative solution is, add your block in content area using block directive via backend. Like this.

```
{{block type="clnews/news" name="right.clnews.latest" template="clnews/latest.phtml" ifconfig="clnews/news/showlatestnews" }}
```

In this case, please make sure your custom block is whitelisted under `System > Permissions > Blocks`

---

<sup>[This answer is a part of #mageStackDay5. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/]</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom theme, you should copy module files (template `.phtml` and layout `.xml`) in your theme.

Copy from `default/default/template/clnews` folder clnews. And from `default/default/layout/clnews.xml`